# Node position with \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I don't understand why the blue "Below" label does not appear right below the "Above" label (near the expected position showed by the red "Below" label). Any idea?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)}
             node[draw, pos = .5] (A) {}
             node[above, sloped, pos = .5] {Above}
             node[below, sloped, pos = .5] {Below};
    \node[rotate = 45, anchor = north, font = \color{red}] at (A.south east) {Below};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Commenting out the "above"-node moves the blue "below"-node to the expected position.

The "below"-node is probably placed below the "above"-node.

Comment: @Grimler Indeed. And reversing above and below is even more confusing!

Comment: I think you get the idea if you place `coordinate[pos=0] (a)` in between them the second one is placed over the path of the first node path. Because pgfplots delays the drawing until everything is parsed I think the last one wins over the actual path.

Comment: @percusse Ok. So it looks like a bug for me. Let's see if Christian comes with a workaround.

Comment: Try this one `\addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,1)} foreach \i in {0,...,40}{node[pos=.5]{.}};`. A strange drift for me.

Comment: [Ticket added](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/94/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is why:

In Ti*k*Z, the `pos=.5` option is handled by `\tikz@timer` with the argument stored in `\tikz@time`. The pgfplots package redefined this macro by

```
pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex

8178    \let\tikz@timer=\pgfplots@plot@timer%

7809    \def\pgfplots@plot@timer{%
7810        \pgfplotstransformplotattime{\tikz@time}%
7811    }

7819    \def\pgfplotstransformplotattime#1{%
7820      \pgftransformshift{\pgfplotspointplotattime{#1}}%
7821      \ifpgfresetnontranslationattime%
7822        \pgftransformresetnontranslations%
7823      \fi%
7824      \ifpgfslopedattime%
7825     \pgfplotsplothandlertransformslopedattime{#1}{\pgfplotspointplotattimefirst}{\pgfplotspointplotattimesecond}%
7826     \fi%
7827    }
```

In this question, nodes are not positioned properly. So we now focus on line 7820.

Recall that `\pgftransformshift` is a macro with one argument. The argument will be executed first and (usually) it will calculate `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`. And then PGF will shift `(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)`. (see also the manual and `pgfcoretransformations.code.tex`)

In other words, `\pgfplotspointplotattime{#1}` should setup `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` properly. Here is (ideally) how `\pgfplotspointplotattime` should work:

- if this `\tikz@time` is used before, reuse the calculated values.
- If not, calculate values and cache them.

And here is ideally how your code will be processed

- `node[draw, pos = .5] (A) {}` --> new `\tikz@time`, calculate everything and cache them.
- `node[above, sloped, pos = .5] {Above}` --> same `\tikz@time`, reuse.
- `node[below, sloped, pos = .5] {Below}` --> same `\tikz@time`, reuse.

It turns out that when `\tikz@time` is not new, pgfplots does not setup `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` properly. The fact that the `Above` node is placed correctly is pure luck --- no one changes the values of `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` so it is placed in the same place. However the values are changed when the `Above` node is typeset, therefore the `Before` node is not placed correctly.

The following example back-ups the observation above.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)}
                node[pos=.3]{.3 new value}
                node[pos=.7]{.7 new value}
                node[pos=.3]{.3 should reuse}
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following example, on the other hand, shows that pgfplots does cache other information such as slope.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1.2,-.2)(1,1)}
                node[pos=.3,sloped]{.3 new value}
                node[pos=.7,sloped]{.7 new value}
                node[pos=.3,sloped]{.3 should reuse}
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

To fix this problem, one may try `pos=.49999` to force pgfplots to recalculate everything. Or one might change the definition of `\pgfplotspointplotattimeaddtocache` to

```
\def\pgfplotspointplotattimeaddtocache#1{%
    \pgfplotsutil@advancestringcounter@global\pgfplotspointplotattime@cachesize
    \ifnum\pgfplotspointplotattime@cachesize=\pgfplotspointplotattime@cachesize@max
        \pgfplotspointplotattimeclearcache
    \fi
    \pgf@xa=#1pt %
    \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{%
        \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\pgfplotspointplotattimefirst{\pgfplotspointplotattimefirst}%
        \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\pgfplotspointplotattimesecond{\pgfplotspointplotattimesecond}%
        \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\pgfplotspointplotattimecoords{\pgfplotspointplotattimecoords}%
        \pgf@x\the\pgf@x % ADDED NEW LINES
        \pgf@y\the\pgf@y % ADDED NEW LINES
    }%
    \t@pgfplots@toka=\expandafter{\pgfplotspointplotattime@cache}%
    \t@pgfplots@tokb=\expandafter{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
    \xdef\pgfplotspointplotattime@cache{%
        \the\t@pgfplots@toka
        \noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/@pos \the\pgf@xa/segment \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pos segment}}{\the\t@pgfplots@tokb}%
    }%
}
```

so that it will remember the position.

---

## MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \def\pgfplotspointplotattimeaddtocache#1{%
        \pgfplotsutil@advancestringcounter@global\pgfplotspointplotattime@cachesize
        \ifnum\pgfplotspointplotattime@cachesize=\pgfplotspointplotattime@cachesize@max
            \pgfplotspointplotattimeclearcache
        \fi
        \pgf@xa=#1pt %
        \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{%
            \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\pgfplotspointplotattimefirst{\pgfplotspointplotattimefirst}%
            \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\pgfplotspointplotattimesecond{\pgfplotspointplotattimesecond}%
            \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\pgfplotspointplotattimecoords{\pgfplotspointplotattimecoords}%
            \pgf@x\the\pgf@x % ADDED NEW LINES
            \pgf@y\the\pgf@y % ADDED NEW LINES
        }%
        \t@pgfplots@toka=\expandafter{\pgfplotspointplotattime@cache}%
        \t@pgfplots@tokb=\expandafter{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
        \xdef\pgfplotspointplotattime@cache{%
            \the\t@pgfplots@toka
            \noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/@pos \the\pgf@xa/segment \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pos segment}}{\the\t@pgfplots@tokb}%
        }%
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1.2,-.2)(1,1)}
                node[pos=.3,sloped]{.3 new value}
                node[pos=.7,sloped]{.7 new value}
                node[pos=.3,sloped]{.3 should reuse}
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record: Your solution is now incorporated into PGFPlots v1.16, which should be available on CTAN later this day. Many thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 7):

Workaround, which uses a simple sloped rectangular node `A` with a width. The height does not matter and can be zero. Then the line `(A.west) -- (A.east)` is used to place the annotation texts:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzstyle{phantomhelper} = [
  rectangle,
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  sloped,
  inner sep=0pt,
  outer sep=0pt,
  minimum width=10mm,
  minimum height=0em,
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)}
      node[pos=.5, phantomhelper] (A) {}
    ;
    \path (A.west) -- (A.east)
          node[pos=.5, above, sloped] {Above}
          node[pos=.5, below, sloped] {Below}
    ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]