# How to make TikZ remember the "sloped" option at later stages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

It is useful to have the "sloped" option in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (C0) at (0pt,0pt) []{$C_0$};
 \node (C1) at (100pt,100pt) []{$C_1$};
 \draw[->] (a)--(b) node [sloped,above]{\text{an isotopy from $C_0$ to $C_1$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but is also useful to "externalize" the drawing the annotation of the arrow from (a) to (b) by naming the node and drawing it later, such as in:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.5]
 \node (C0) at (0pt,0pt) []{$C_0$};
 \node (C1) at (100pt,100pt) []{$C_1$};
 \draw[->] (a)--(b) node (positionofannotation) [sloped,above]{};
\end{scope}
 \node (nameofannotation) at (positionofannotation) [sloped]{$\text{an isotopy from $C_0$ to $C_1$}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

whereupon the "sloped" option becomes ineffective.

How to make TikZ "remember" that this node is to be "drawn sloped"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borrowing from [an idea of Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272073/116936)

### The output

Added an obstacle to show the node is drawn later than the path.

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.5]
    \node (C0) at (0pt,0pt) []{$C_0$};
    \node (C1) at (100pt,100pt) []{$C_1$};
    \draw[->] (C0)--(C1) node (positionofannotation) [sloped,midway] {};
  \end{scope}

  \fill [red!10, rounded corners] (25pt,25pt) rectangle (75pt,75pt);

  \path (positionofannotation.west) -- (positionofannotation.east) 
      node (nameofannotation) [midway, above, sloped, font=\scriptsize] 
        {an isotopy from $C_0$ to $C_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```