# pos= syntax within \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I read [in this answer by Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375840/116936) that pgfplots redefines the `\tikz@timer` used in `pos=<pos>`.

This redefinition seems to effectively replace `<pos>` to denote the ratio :

```
<arc length start-current point>/<total arc length>
```

Is it possible to still use the old TikZ definition of `<pos>` as a ratio of numbers of arc segments ?

### Example

For instance,

> Is it possible to position inside the `\addplot` the node reading `positioned afterwards` ?

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    declare function=
    {
      absc(\x)=cos(\x^2);
      ordo(\x)=sin(\x^2);
    },
    every node/.style={fill=white,}
  ]
  \begin{axis}
    [
      height=15cm,
      clip=none,
      unit vector ratio = 1 1,
      axis lines = center,
    ]


    \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxParam}{sqrt(180)}
    \addplot+[domain=0:\maxParam] ({absc(x)},{ordo(x)}) 
      node [pos=.5] {positioned by \texttt{pos=.5}};

    \node at ({absc(.5*\maxParam)},{ordo(.5*\maxParam)}) {positioned afterwards};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but I guess you mean something like the [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/61/) requested feature, right?

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly your requested feature, I suppose that would be my question. To express `pos` as a *ratio of the domain* (like in TikZ), instead of as *a ratio of arc length*. `(Am i not being clear enough ?)` But if I understand correctly the linked explanation by Symbol1, the feature natively exists, but is **overwritten**.

Comment: Remark: @StefanPinnow's feature request lasts five months because there are (at least) two data structures involved. (1) With raw data it is nature to calculate `pos` w.r.t. segments. (2) With pgf soft path it is nature to calculate `pos` w.r.t. arc length....... The problem is, we are given only one data structure and it is difficult to **disobey** the nature...